# How do I find records that are not joined?

Tags: sql, select, join, anti-join

I have two tables that are joined together.

A has many B

Normally you would do:

```
select * from a,b where b.a_id = a.id
```

To get all of the records from a that has a record in b.

How do I get just the records in a that does not have anything in b?

Answer (score 142, accepted):

```
select * from a where id not in (select a_id from b)
```

Or like some other people on this thread says:

```
select a.* from a
left outer join b on a.id = b.a_id
where b.a_id is null
```

Comment: it's better to use left outer join because "in" could have limitation (depends on db)

Answer (score 28):

```
select * from a
left outer join b on a.id = b.a_id
where b.a_id is null
```

Comment: I think this left outer join will perform much better than the 'in' clause, unless the query optimizer treats them the same...

Comment: It pretty much does.  Check it out.

Comment: Yeah, interestingly, the query plan has an extra strep (Filter) for the left join and the 'where in' is resolved to a 'right anti semi join'...whatever that is...

Comment: According to answers in [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2930033/t-sql-left-outer-joins-filters-in-the-where-clause-versus-the-on-clause), this won't work: "If you filter the left outer joined table in the WHERE clause then you are in effect creating an inner join"

Answer (score 15):

The following image will help to understand SQL **LET JOIN** :

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Another approach:

```
select * from a where not exists (select * from b where b.a_id = a.id)
```

The "exists" approach is useful if there is some other "where" clause you need to attach to the inner query.

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT id FROM a
EXCEPT
SELECT a_id FROM b;
```

Comment: The `EXCEPT` keyword is `MINUS` in Oracle.

Answer (score 4):

You will probably get a lot better performance (than using 'not in') if you use an outer join:

```
select * from a left outer join b on a.id = b.a_id where b.a_id is null;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT <columnns>
FROM a WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT a_id FROM b)
```

Comment: This will be extremely expensive as the engine has to generate the the subquery in its entirety before it can begin to eliminate the tuples from a. Not a good idea in general.

Answer (score 1):

Another way of writing it

```
select a.*
from a 
left outer join b
on a.id = b.id
where b.id is null
```

Ouch, beaten by Nathan :)

Answer (score 1):

In case of one join it is pretty fast, but when we are removing records from database which has about 50 milions records and 4 and more joins due to foreign keys, it takes a few minutes to do it.
Much faster to use WHERE NOT IN condition like this:

```
select a.* from a
where a.id NOT IN(SELECT DISTINCT a_id FROM b where a_id IS NOT NULL)
//And for more joins
AND a.id NOT IN(SELECT DISTINCT a_id FROM c where a_id IS NOT NULL)
```

I can also recommended this approach for deleting in case we don't have configured cascade delete.
This query takes only a few seconds.

Answer (score 1):

The first approach is

```
select a.* from a where a.id  not in (select b.ida from b)
```

the second approach is

```
select a.*
  from a left outer join b on a.id = b.ida
  where b.ida is null
```

The first approach is very expensive. The second approach is better.

With PostgreSql 9.4, I did the "explain query" function and the first query as a cost of *cost=0.00..1982043603.32*.
Instead the join query as a cost of *cost=45946.77..45946.78*

For example, I search for all products that are not compatible with no vehicles. I've 100k products and more than 1m compatibilities.

```
select count(*) from product a left outer join compatible c on a.id=c.idprod where c.idprod is null
```

The join query spent about 5 seconds, instead the subquery version has never ended after 3 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

This will protect you from nulls in the IN clause, which can cause unexpected behavior.

select * from a where id not in (select [a id] from b where **[a id] is not null**)

Comment: You are better off using a left outer join rather than using an IN predicate in the first place.